# Can Phonegap run javascript when the program is closed?

Tags: cordova

I think the answer is no because the timers in my app seem to stop running.  Yet there is a closed handler, so it seems that javascript can be run at the moment of close...

If the answer is no, how would you create an app that could periodically check a remote server for new messages (and then send a push notification so the user opens the app)?

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

i guess the answer would be to start a service when the app is launched which pings the server periodically..  nothing in phonegap for this, u would have to write a bit of java code.
check out android service.

Answer (score 0):

I am also unable to run any Javascript when the app is closed ("paused"). According to the iOS quirks, the code is executed when the app resumes (I have confirmed this), which seems completely asinine.

---

I believe this was added in iOS 5, but there is a new "resign" event that fires before the "pause" event and it WILL allow you to execute Javascript as the app is closing :D

```
function onResign() {
  //App is closing...do what you must!
}

document.addEventListener('resume', onResign, false);
```